# CSS "overflow:scroll" not working for chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, iframe, webkit

I have an `iframe` and I need the scrollbars to be present even when content fits inside the `iframe`. so used `overflow:scroll` property . which works fine for FF, IE but not in chrome.

```
#iframeid
{
    height:500; width:1150
}
#iframeid::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 12px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

this totally removes the scrollbars. Any thing I am missing ?

Comment: is the content of the iframe from the same domain of the parent?

Comment: no.. its a external content.. but this doesnt work for same domain either.

Comment: has the iframed page a fixed layout or responsive? you could wrap the iframe in a div and make the iframe with fixed size, applying scrollbars to the wrapper

Comment: If I do that, I could make the scrollbar of the div to scroll only the iframe but not the iframe contents.

Comment: this way http://jsfiddle.net/62nAZ/

Answer (score 1):

Use scrolling attribute in iframe..

> `<iframe width="150" height="150" scrolling="yes/no/auto"></iframe>`

Comment: While this may work for the OP, it's not a supported feature of HTML5.  A CSS solution would be best.

Comment: Chrome will ignore the CSS solution of setting overflow to auto or scroll if the scrolling attribute is set to no

Answer (score 0):

All the CSS you need:

```
#iframeid{
    height:500; width:1150
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

Works for me in Chrome:
http://jsfiddle.net/ukcG9/6/

Comment: it still doesnt show the scrollbar when the content is fit in the iframe. All I need is to show scrolbar inspite of the content.